# Overriding < in Pharo

Tags: overriding, smalltalk, pharo

I am trying to override the '<' operator in pharo, because i want to have a SortedCollection of a class i have implemented (TimeCal).

TimeCal has the following variables: year month day hour minute.

My idea was to convert all the variables to minutes, and then compare those with the comparand that the < operator receives. I do, however, get an error

"BlockClosure(Object)>>doesNotUnderstand: #>"

And here is my code:

```
< comparand
| thisInMins comparandInMins |
thisInMins := [(year * 525600) + (month * 43829) + (day * 1440) + (hour * 60) + minute].
comparandInMins := [(comparand year * 525600) + (comparand month * 43829) + (comparand day * 1440) + (comparand hour * 60) + comparand minute].

(thisInMins > comparandInMins)
ifTrue: [true] ifFalse: [false]
```

And the code i use to test it:

```
time1 := TimeCal new. 
time1 hour: 12.
time1 day: 12.
time1 month: 11.
time2 := TimeCal new. 
time2 hour: 12.
time2 day: 12.
time2 month: 8.
testing := time1 < time2.
```

I am not sure if what I am doing is correct. I could not find any proper guide on how to do it.

Comment: `thisInMins` and `comparandInMins` variables are blocks (type BlockClosure), which do not understand #< nor #>.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks a lot, I had no idea they were of type BlockClosure.

Comment: They were of type `BlockClosure` because you enclosed them in `[` and `]`. Remove those square brackets (as MartinW did, see his answer) and you'll get the value of what's inside that block. Also, instead of setting each hour/day/month value manually, you should consider creating a method on the class side to set those variables on a new instance and return the instance.

Comment: Are you aware of Timestamp class? Because it means the same that your TimeCal, but using a different representation and it is fully implemented

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter - if I removed the block I got an error that it didn't understand #*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this

```
< other
    year = other year ifFalse: [^year < other year].
    month = other month ifFalse: [^month < other month].
    day = other day ifFalse: [^day < other day].
    hour = other hour ifFalse: [^hour < other hour].
    ^minute < other minute
```

Comment: Very well written: small and elegant

Answer (score 3):

If you have properly initialized your variables, this should work:

```
< comparand
| thisInMins comparandInMins |
thisInMins := (year * 525600) + (month * 43829) + (day * 1440) + (hour * 60) + minute.
comparandInMins := (comparand year * 525600) + (comparand month * 43829) + (comparand day * 1440) + (comparand hour * 60) + comparand minute.

^ thisInMins < comparandInMins
```

Why did you put square brackets around your minutes calculations?

Also have a look at this: `ifTrue: [true] ifFalse: [false]`. Returning true if something is true and false if something is false seems an unnecessary step. You can return the result of your comparison of minutes directly.

Comment: I tried a lot of things to see if I could get it to work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edit: When i remove the square brackets it gives me an error with the * operations. It does however still not work, i get the same error.

Comment: Does it say _MessageNotUnderstood: receiver of "*" is nil_? That's probably because you did not initialize your variables to zero. Add an `initialize` method and initialize your variables. In Pharo `initialize` is called when you create a new instance of a class.